# <p contenteditable="true"> equates to string.length 4 when cleared

Tags: javascript

I don't want the user to be able to send a blank text message. When the user clears the p tag and clicks send..it returns as string.length to 4, when it should be 0. I also want the user to send a message and alert it to the window and record it in the textarea.

The code : https://codepen.io/CandidSpace/pen/vbLbjY

```
    <p id="sendMe"  onclick="myFunky()" contenteditable="true">
      Highlight all of the text you see here, including this and delete 
      it, and this, then enter a message..click send!
    </p><br>

    <button class="button" onclick="myFun()">Send</button><br>

    <textarea onclick="myFunk()" id="message" rows="4" cols="50" readonly>           
   </textarea>

    <script>

      function myFunk() {

        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Please delete the 
        above    line 'Highlight all of the text you see here, including 
        this and delete it, and this, then enter a message..click send!'. 
        Thank you!"
      }

      function myFunky() {

        document.getElementById("sendMe").style.color = "black";
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML= "That's It!";
      }

      function myFun() {
        document.getElementById("sendMe").style.color = "blue";
        document.getElementById("message").style.color = "red";

        var str = document.getElementById("sendMe").innerHTML;
        var x = str.valueOf();
        var y = str.length;
        var n = str.includes("Highlight all of the text you see here, including  this and delete it, and this, then enter a message..click send!");


        if (n == true) {

          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Delete the above line &    write a text!";
        } else if (x == 0) {
          alert ("That was Blank!");
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Don't be shy! Come on  write some text!!";
        } else {

          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Your text:  " 
          +str+ "    was recorded momentarily";
          document.getElementById("message").style.color = "green";
          document.getElementById("sendMe").innerHTML = ""
          alert ("Thank you for your time and text: " +str + "  the
          string.length of your text = " + y + " characters in length.");
        }
      };

    </script>
```

Comment: Your text area contains characters. Keep it empty like so:
```<textarea onclick="myFunk()" id="message" rows="4" cols="50" readonly></textarea>```

Comment: I checked and its ok. Please mark my answer as the correct one. Thanks

Comment: This is an answer to a different problem! that you have not found yet. It is not needed in the above solution as you could see in the code.

Comment: I know that I am correct & I showed you the value 0 (zero) on which you could do whatever you wanted. But honestly, you rejected my answer for no good reason - so let stop bother each other.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand

Comment: @Mulli I think because your demo had text in the p content editable tag I wasn't able to understand. But I do now ! Thank you :-) BTW I haven't got enough reps to mark your answer as correct. Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: https://codepen.io/CandidSpace/pen/OdbOrN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text area contains characters. Keep it empty like so:

`<textarea onclick="myFunk()" id="message" rows="4" cols="50" readonly></textarea>`

You may [see it in action here](https://codepen.io/mulli/pen/YBwBmy)

EDIT: add image of result [image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me understand!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<body style="background-color:yellow;">

<p id="sendMe" onclick="myFunky()" contenteditable="true">Highlight all of the   text you see here, including this and delete it, and this, then enter a message..click send!</p><br>

<button class="button" onclick="myFun()">Send</button><br>

<textarea onclick="myFunk()" id="message" rows="4" cols="50" readonly> </textarea>




function myFunk() {

document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Please delete the above line    'Highlight all of the text you see here, including this and delete it, and this, then enter a message..click send!'. Thank you!"
}
function myFunky() {

document.getElementById("sendMe").style.color = "black";
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML= "That's It send me a text!";
}

function myFun() {
document.getElementById("sendMe").style.color = "blue";
document.getElementById("message").style.color = "red";

var str = document.getElementById("sendMe").innerHTML;
var x = str.valueOf();
var y = str.length;
var v = str.includes("<br>");
var n = str.includes("Highlight all of the text you see here, including this  and delete it, and this, then enter a message..click send!");


if (v==true || y==0) {
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Write a text!!";
alert ("Don't be cheeky ! That was a blank text!");

} else if (n==false){

document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Your text:  " +str+ " was   recorded momentarily";
document.getElementById("message").style.color = "green";
document.getElementById("sendMe").innerHTML = ""
alert ("Thank you for your time and text: " +x);
}

else {


alert ("You haven't sent a message");
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Don't be shy! Come on write some    text!!";

}
};
```

Comment: the string.length = 4 was <br>. Why this value appears by default I have no idea ! I simply used string.value() to find it ( I was blind) and string.includes to remove it. https://codepen.io/CandidSpace/pen/MLbgva

Comment: A simpler method would be to follow what @Mulli suggested. Don't have any text in the p content editable tag to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body id="Bground" onclick="myFunky()" style="background-color:#ff3110;">
<h4> Please send me a message!</h4> <h5>Text me on the dotted line:</h5>

<p id="sendMe"  onclick="myFunky()" contenteditable="true" style="border- bottom:dotted; width:500px"></p><br>

<button class="button" onclick="myFun()">Send</button><br>

<textarea id="message" rows="4" cols="50" readonly></textarea>

function myFunky() {
document.getElementById("Bground").style.backgroundColor = "white";
document.getElementById("sendMe").style.backgroundColor = "red";
document.getElementById("sendMe").style.color = "white";
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML= "That's It!";
}

function myFun() {
document.getElementById("sendMe").style.color = "blue";
document.getElementById("message").style.color = "red";

var str = document.getElementById("sendMe").innerHTML;
var x = str.valueOf();
var y = str.length;
//var n = str.includes("Highlight all of the text you see here, including  this  and delete it, and this, then enter a message..click send!");


if (y == 0){
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="You have not entered any text!";
alert ("Please enter some text to send! Make it snappy!")
} else if (x==0){

alert ("That was Blank!"+str.length);
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML ="Don't be shy! Come on  write some text!!";
}

else {

document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Your text:>  " +str+ " <:was  recorded momentarily";
document.getElementById("message").style.color = "green";
document.getElementById("sendMe").innerHTML = ""
alert ("Thank you for your time! Your Text:> " +str+ " <:has been received!");

}
};
```

Comment: This is the code with help of Multi, that I tidied up! https://codepen.io/CandidSpace/pen/OdbOrN